# Bash - Using "find" in while loop is giving blank results with input from DOS text file

Tags: bash, while-loop, find

I have a text file that contains a list of file names without the folder path or extension. I want to loop over this file and find the path that matches the file name. However, my find command inside the while loop is not giving me the result. The find command works when I take it out of the while loop.

Here is my example input file (input.txt):

```
12345
56789
...
09987
89008
```

The actual files are stored like this:

```
/home/user/path/to/file/12345.jpg
```

Here is my script (find_files.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
    file=$(find /home/engage/ -name "${line}*" -print)
    echo $file
done < "$1"
```

And I'm calling it with:

```
./find_files.sh input.txt
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
12345

56789
...
09987

89008
```

So `find` is not getting any results. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you run `cat -v input.txt`, does it show `^M` after every line?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes it does

Comment: BTW, `echo $line` doesn't tell you anything useful about what's in `$line` -- or at least, not nearly as much as you think it does. `echo "$line"` is slightly better; `printf '%q\n' "$line"` is *much* better... and just running `bash -x yourscript` to print each command before it's executed in an unambiguous format (which would show hidden characters such as the linefeeds throwing you off here) instead of peppering it with `echo` calls is even better than that.

Comment: See entry #14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay, thank you for the tips!

Comment: BTW -- change `while read line` to `while IFS= read -r line` to correct handling of filenames ending in whitespace and filenames containing literal backslash characters. If you also want to handle filenames with literal newlines (which are in fact legal on UNIX!) correctly, then you'd need to change your file format to be NUL-delimited rather than newline-delimited.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Done. I took that out because my file names were all digits.

Comment: Incidentally, one of my best true-story cautionary tales (in which multiple TB of backups of data used for billing were deleted) is of a case where filenames "couldn't possibly" contain anything but characters in `[0-9a-f]`... but then a new service writing to the directory came online, which turned out to have a bug that could cause random memory corruption, which one day created a filename which (among other random/nonprintable garbage) had an asterisk surrounded by whitespace... and the cleanup script didn't quote its expansions correctly. Moral being, "impossible" things sometimes happen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ouch! Good point. Luckily this was just a one-off script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file has Windows style `\r\n` line endings, and the unexpected `\r` is causing the match to fail.

Delete them from your input file with `dos2unix`, `fromdos` or `tr -d '\r' < input.txt > fixed_input.txt`.

You can alternatively strip them at run time in your loop with `line=${line%$'\r'}`

Comment: Why should I have deleted it? Wouldn't it be good for other people to know?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I looked for other questions before I posted and couldn't find what I wanted. I think someone looking for issues with newlines will have better luck elsewhere, but I didn't know that was the issue. However, someone looking for issues with "find" and "blank results" might find this post helpful. So it seems odd to say that it adds nothing to the knowledgebase. But I respect your opinion and reputation.

Comment: @DrewS, what if we changed the title to specify "with input from DOS text file"? That way people with unrelated problems won't waste their time, and it's easier to find for folks with the same issue.